# Difference between System.setProperty in Java code and <sysproperty/> or <jvmargs> in ant xml

Tags: java, xml, ant, build, jvm-arguments

If I set the property in Java program code, it works:

```
try {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/ylinghao/AllocationAnomaliesDetection/env/AllocationAnomaliesDetection-1.0/runtime/certs/InternalTrustStore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to specify keystore for issue" + e);
    }
```

But If I try setting the property in `<jvmarg>` or `<systproperty>` in build.xml of ant, it fails. Could anyone tell me what is the difference? Thanks!

Comment: Show your build file

Comment: are you using ant xml to run your app or to build your app? If it's for the latter, as it usually is, then this is the answer: whatever you are putting there is not affecting the execution of your application.

Comment: @albert_nil It's build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that on your ant you are doing the build of your application. So the jvm settigns you are configuring there are for the execution of ant itself (or any auxiliar java process you yse, for example, to compile the code).

So in your ant you are not affecting execution of your program, which is done in another java process when you start it.

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting the documentation site here:

> Use nested  elements to specify system properties required by the class. These properties will be made available to the VM during the execution of the class (either ANT's VM or the forked VM). The attributes for this element are the same as for environment variables.

You need to have `fork="true"` to have effect of  `jvmarg` or `sysproperty`.